# Behavior of vector field that is the arg min of a convex function

Tags: convex-optimization, fields, convex-analysis, vector-spaces

Say $f(x,y)$ is a real valued function that is strongly convex and twice differentiable in both $x$ and $y$. Here $x$ and $y$ are real vectors of different dimensions. We define $y^\star(x)= \arg \min_y f(x,y) $. The function $y^\star(x)$ is a vector field. What can we say about $y^\star(x)$? Will it be smooth and well behaved in some sense? Given vectors $x_1$, we can find $y_1 = \arg \min_y f(x_1,y)$by some minimization procedure. Now at some other vector$x_2$, how do we find $y_2 = \arg \min_y f(x_2,y)$ without solving the minimization problem, ie, using only information about $x_1$, $y_1$, $x_2$, the properties of $f(x,y)$ and $y^\star(x)$. Note that there is no closed form expression for $y^\star(x)$, otherwise the problem is a simple substitution.

Comment: I don't think that you can expect smoothness (consider $\|Ax-y\|_1$).

Comment: $\|Ax-y\|_1$ is not strongly convex. Neither is it differentiable.

Comment: Oops, missed that... The implicit function theorem should show smoothness of the argmin in this case.